# 遲 vs. 晚 in Mandarin: when to use which one?

Tags: mandarin, cantonese

In Cantonese, you can use 遲 to indicate someone is late (e.g., not punctual) or the time is late (e.g., past midnight so all restaurants are closed).

However, it seems like Mandarin speakers use 晚 in place of 遲 most of the time.

What are the Mandarin guidelines for using 遲 vs. 晚? Should you just always use 晚?

Comment: Another character that is used for "late" in Cantonese is 晏, which I don't think is used in that way in Mandarin.

Comment: 夜 is also used to mean "late" in Cantonese, as in "late at night".  It is closer to the usage of 晚 in Mandarin.  For example, 你咁夜都仲未返屋企？ in Cantonese would be 你這麼晚還未回家? in Mandarin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

晚 and 遲 are interchangeable when it is used as an adverb for "late"

For example, 晚到= 遲到; 來晚了= 來遲了

But 遲 have the additional meaning of "delay"

Example:

- You can say **遲遲**才回覆 (reply after **long delay**/ reply **very late**) but you can't say  晚晚才回覆
- You can say **遲**則有變 (situations change when you **delay** your action/ situations change when you are **late** to act) but you can't say  晚則有變

Answer (score 2):

迟(the standard simplified Chinese word, while the Chinese Traditional is 遲) and 晚 both have the meaning of late.

- **迟** usually means **late for the appointed time or a certain time**.
  example: Party七点开始，你来**迟**了!—— The party start at 7:00 pm, you came
  late!

  The word '迟到' is frequently used to describe late for certain time
- **晚** is more complex

  It has the meaning of **late for a certain time**.
  example: Party七点开始，你来**晚**了!—— The party start at 7:00 pm, you came
  late!

  It also have the meaning of **just being late** but not for a
  certain time. example: 他很**晚**到家—— He arrived home very late. example:
  他昨晚很**晚**离开—— He left late last night.

  Or it means **evening**. example:
  晚上——evening, example:今**晚**——tonight, example:昨**晚**——last night.

---

Fun fact: to describe public transportation's behind schedule, the word is 晚点, where '点' means the schedule time for public transportation to arrive.

Comment: There is a misspelling 'Parity' in your answer. I guess you meant 'party'.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's meaningless to just compare them without context. Maybe know more phrases can be more helpful.

eg:

I'm late.

correct: 我来晚了，我迟到了，我迟到了
wrong: 我晚了

In many case, they are very similar. But in other case, they different, and can't replace with each other.

eg:

evening/night

correct:晚上/夜晚  (can't use 迟)

delay

correct:延迟  (can't use 晚)

Answer (score 0):

To indicate late, 晚 is more modern while 遲(迟) is more ancient. Cantonese has retained many ancient Chinese language components. 
Both of them is understandable in nowadays communication.